# Sitecore 8.0 - ERROR EmailCampaign: Failed to send 'Subscription Notification' to 'xdb:14c0c3e8-afd6-4344-98ab-5b86dcb4dd30'

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecm

I'm working on Sitecore 8.0 rev 150621 and I'm getting the following error message on my logs.

> MessageTaskRunner worker thread 9 05:07:03 ERROR EmailCampaign: Failed to send 'Subscription Notification' to 'xdb:14c0c3e8-afd6-4344-98ab-5b86dcb4dd30'.

In the fresh logs also I'm getting this error couple of times. I think Sitecore tries to send subscription email message to the subscriber: `14c0c3e8-afd6-4344-98ab-5b86dcb4dd30`.

Does anyone have an idea about how to find this user on the Sitecore xDB ? 
I tried to find it on the Analytics mongoDB database using the following query:

```
db.Contacts.find({'_id' : '14c0c3e8-afd6-4344-98ab-5b86dcb4dd30'})
```

But I couldn't find any results.
Am I doing it correctly ? or Am I looking at the wrong database table or field ?

Please advice me on this.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Detail error:

```
MessageTaskRunner worker thread 3 12:45:46 ERROR EmailCampaign: Failed to send 'Subscription Notification' to 'xdb:14c0c3e8-afd6-4344-98ab-5b86dcb4dd30'.
MessageTaskRunner worker thread 3 12:45:46 ERROR EmailCampaign: Message sending error: System.InvalidOperationException: Custom Data does not contain specified key.
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.AutomationStateContext.UpdateCustomData(String keyName, Object value)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Gateways.DefaultAnalyticsGateway.EnrollOrUpdateContact(Contact contact, Guid planId, Guid stateId, EcmCustomValues customValues, String[] validStates)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Gateways.DefaultAnalyticsGateway.EnrollOrUpdateContact(Guid contactId, Guid planId, Guid automationStateId, EcmCustomValues customValues, String[] validStates)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Analytics.AutomationStatesManager.EnrollOrUpdateContact(Guid contactId, Guid planId, String stateName, EcmCustomValues customValues, String[] validStates)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.EnrollOrUpdateContact(Guid contactId, DispatchQueueItem dispatchQueueItem, Guid planId, String stateName, EcmCustomValues customValues)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
```

Comment: Are there any updates on this question? Did my answer help you?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried this one (which exists in the database) but It didn't throw me any results. Can you advice me how to query this:  "_id" : LUUID("551a51c7-9884-f845-8277-35504b4f5d79"). I tried to query this as: db.Contacts.find({_id : 'VRpRx5iE+EWCdzVQS09deQ=='}). But it didn't throw any results. Am I doing this correct ?

Comment: According to the first link, you should do this: `db.Contacts.find({_id : new BinData(3, 'VRpRx5iE+EWCdzVQS09deQ==')})`

Comment: Oh I missed that. Thank you. It works. But I'm not sure Sitecore save the subscriber in this table.

Comment: I can see that you've unmarked my answer as accepted. Is there something that is incorrect in my answer? Is there a way I can improve it?

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate this error coming in the logs ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot query `_id`s as strings, since they are stored in a special binary format. The conversion is handled by the C# driver. There are a couple ways to query GUIDs from the mongo shell. Please take a look at these StackOverflow answers:

- [How do I use a guid in a mongodb shell query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652107/how-do-i-use-a-guid-in-a-mongodb-shell-query)
- [Get BinData UUID from Mongo as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244110/get-bindata-uuid-from-mongo-as-string/)

In regards to the error you are receiving, there *has* to be an exception logged with more details on what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your contact list, I think there must be some incorrect information. Have you imported contact list via csv file? Check correctness of data. The same issue happened with me and it took me long to figure out issue with my contact list.