# MongoDB - find where BinData is equal to UUID value

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I try to write application in Java and Spring Data MongoDB.

My document looks:

```
@Data
@ToString
public class SomeDocument {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SomeDocumentMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeDocument, UUID> {
}
```

It's very simple. And I saved the document:

```
{
    "id": "5f4ac46b-55f7-4be4-b26f-2ca041334bec",
    "name": "some name"
}
```

Then I tried to read it from database using simple query `db.someDocument.find()` and I've got the result:

```
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"5Ev3VWvESl/sSzNBoCxvsg=="), "name" : "some name", "_class" : "org.springmongodemo.repo.SomeDocument" }
```

So my questions are:

1. How to find in mongo shell document by `_id` using given `UUID`?
2. What does mean number 3 in `BinData(3,...)`?

Comment: Do you need to use UUIDs? Can you not perhaps switch to ObjectId? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Answer (score 1):

1. To find the document you'd have to encode your UUID into base64. [Please see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652107/how-do-i-use-a-guid-in-a-mongodb-shell-query).
2. "3" is the identifier for legacy UUID data format. For more please [see here](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-best-practices-uuid-data/).

If you want to query from in-app you should use Spring Data's features, but from your question I assume you want to know how to query using mongo native tools.